# ASP.NET MVC -- How to Format URL Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

How to I format a query string so it looks like this

search?q=power+tools

currently it looks like this

search?q=power%20tools

Is there a way to do this without replacing the space for a plus sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx)

In a ASP.NET page HttpServerUtility instance can be accessed by Page.Server property.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(loband).aspx) encodes it that way, and that is what is used by pretty much everything in ASP.NET.

<strike>Besides, from memory %20 is actually correct for query strings, and + is correct for URLs.</strike> Ignore this, it's incorrect.